# Symmetry planes in spherical harmonic basis

Tags: symmetry, orthogonal-polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

Suppose I have a function $f(x):S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ in the **degree four** spherical harmonic basis:
$$f(\theta,\varphi):=\sum_{k=-4}^4a_kY_4^k(\theta,\varphi).$$
I have two related questions:

- Is there a simple formula and/or system of equations that can be used
  to find the planes through the origin over which $f(\cdot)$ has
  reflectional symmetry?
- Is there a condition on the $a_k$'s that guarantees that the symmetry planes of $f$ are mutually orthogonal?

---

The only symmetry I could find was the much simpler $f(x)=f(-x)$, but this represents reflection through the origin rather than over a plane.  I tried thinking about degree-four homogeneous polynomials instead but couldn't find any elegant way to approach this problem.  Given all the nice identities about spherical harmonics, I was hoping this would have an elegant solution...

I am interested in this topic because I'm curious what happens to the functions in Figure 9 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03351) when the xyz axes are allowed to scale independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2013/papers/Kakarala_Three-Dimensional_Bilateral_Symmetry_2013_CVPR_paper.pdf) does a good job explaining the details.

Take $v\in\mathbb{C}^{2\ell+1}$ to be the coefficients of a function in the degree-$\ell$ part of the spherical harmonic basis.  Reflecting over the $xz$ plane is equivalent to conjugation: $v\mapsto v^\ast$.

So, if $N$ is the normal to the reflectional symmetry plane, take $P$ to be any matrix rotating $N$ to the $+y$ axis.  If $D_\ell(P)$ is the corresponding Wigner-$D$ matrix, then we can obtain a symmetric reflection by rotating the function so that the symmetry plane is $xz$, then rotating back:  $v\mapsto v^\ast D_\ell(P)^\ast D_\ell(P)^\dagger$ (here $\ast$ denotes conjugation and $\dagger$ denotes a conjugate transpose).

After lots of playing with the Wigner-$D$ matrix formula in Mathematica, it does not appear that there is any particularly nice condition guaranteeing that the rotated function has orthogonal symmetry planes...